# How can you save the last language displayed with local storage? I used counterpart.registerTranslations for translate the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

How can you save the last language displayed with local storage?
I used counterpart.registerTranslations for translate the page.

This is my code:

```
import counterpart from 'counterpart';
import Translate from 'react-translate-component';

import en from './lang/en';
import de from './lang/de';

counterpart.registerTranslations('en', en);
counterpart.registerTranslations('de', de);

counterpart.setLocale('en');

class App extends Component {
  state = {
   lang: 'en'
}

onLangChange = e => {
   this.setState({lang: e.target.value}); // switch the state
   counterpart.setLocale(e.target.value);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <select value={this.state.lang} onChange={this.onLangChange}>
                <option value="en">English</option>
                <option value="de">German</option>
            </select>
            <Translate content="title" component="h1"/>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Source code here::
https://github.com/ChigabigaChannel/reacthourprojects/tree/master/multi-lang-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onLangChange` method you can use `localStorage.setItem('lang', e.target.value)` to store the selected language to localStorage.

(It's OK to name it just like `lang` as it will be stored related to the domain that is calling `setItem` so no need to prefix it with anything.)

Next, use it as an initial value for your state

```js
state = {
   lang: localStorage.getItem('lang')
}
```

So our state is now updated to the stored value but `counterpart` locale is not set correctly. You have to create a `componentDidUpdate` life-cycle method like in the following snippet:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // maybe add a check here to be sure the locale changed
  counterpart.setLocale(this.props.locale)
}
```

To make this work you would need to wrap your `LocaleSwitcher` into a component and add the `componentDidUpdate` there. But with React [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) you could do it in an `useEffect` to run it as a side effect.

I've created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-lederberg-nnrnf) with the hook example. (If you need help with the class-based approach please let me know)

The `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    counterpart.setLocale(lang);
  }, [lang]);
```

Will run whenever `lang` state changes. So that the locale is always set correctly.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate the answer but how could I do to keep my sintax "class App extends Component " it's part of a more complex project and I wouldn't want to change everything

Comment: Sure, you could move the `LanguageSelector` to it's own component. Like in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-haslett-0o012).